# How attach and debugging .net core in Ubuntu visual studio code?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

in Net Framework and visual studio in debug menu can attach to your process and debug code . in net core and visual studio code how do debugging?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code#debug